# Currently running fragment closes and gets back into previous activity when try to import photo from gallery

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

## Currently running fragment closes and gets back into previous activity when trying to import photo from gallery and set it to ImageView.

**I want to set the imported image to an ImageView which is in the fragment. But when I select the image it closes the current fragment and goes back to the previous activity.**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 1000){
            try {
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
                bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);

                ImageView iv = getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want choose an image from the gallery and set it to an ImageView which is in the currently running fragment without getting closing it.

I tried putting **getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();** in OnActivityResult() in my fragment. But it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the 2 Activities you are using?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Please post the logcat error message